# Bash command to check if Oracle or OpenJDK java version is installed on Linux

Tags: java, linux, bash

I need a bash line to check if java version currently installed is Oracle's or OpenJDK.

A one-liner by parsing the output of the `java -version` command:

```
java -version
```

java Oracle output:

```
java version "1.7.0_80"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_80-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.80-b11, mixed mode)
```

java OpenJDK Output:

```
java version "1.7.0_91"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (amzn-2.6.2.2.63.amzn1-x86_64 u91-b00)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.91-b01, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
if [[ $(java -version 2>&1) == *"OpenJDK"* ]]; then echo ok; else echo 'not ok'; fi
```

Answer (score 27):

```
java -version 2>&1 | grep "OpenJDK Runtime" | wc -l
```

returns 0 if using Oracle JDK, 1 if using OpenJDK

Bash condition:

```
if [[ $(java -version 2>&1 | grep "OpenJDK Runtime") ]]
```

Comment: Bash condition can be written as `if java -version 2>&1 | grep -q "OpenJDK Runtime"; then ...`. No need for `[[ ... ]]` or `$( ... )`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use below shell script for you work:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a JAVA=($(sudo find / -name java | grep -v grep | grep "/bin/java"))

for javapath in "${JAVA[@]}"
do 
 if [[ $(sudo  ${javapath} -version 2>&1) != *"OpenJDK"* ]]; then 
    export JAVAVER=$(${javapath} -version 2>&1);
    echo "Java Location -- ${javapath}"
    echo "${JAVAVER}"

 fi
done
```

NOTE: This will cover all java executable files running on you hosts.